# How to conditionally add a Angular Material directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using Angular 5 and Angular Material 5.

I want to conditionally add either a `mat-button` or `mat-menu-item` directive.

I'm doing this using a directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-attr]'
})
export class DynamicAttrDirective {
  @Input('dynamic-attr') attr: string;
  private _el: ElementRef;

  constructor(el: ElementRef,  private _renderer: Renderer) {
    this._el = el;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.attr === '') return null;
    const node = document.createAttribute(this.attr);
    this._el.nativeElement.setAttributeNode(node);
  }
}
```

Like so:

```
<button dynamic-attr="{{ isCollapsed ? 'mat-menu-item' : 'mat-button'}}" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>
```

But while this renders the attribute in the resulting mark up, the Material Design styling and additional mark up (for ripples etc) is not applied.

```
  <div _ngcontent-c1="" app-nav-menu="" ng-reflect-is-collapsed="false"><button tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/about" mat-button="" ng-reflect-attr="mat-button">About</button>
```

I'm guessing something like $compile from AngularJS is needed.

How can I do this?

**NOTE:** Ideally I want to avoid using if/else. I'd like to write the code for the buttons once and simply toggle the directive (mat-button / mat-menu-item)

**UPDATE:** The problem I am trying to solve is removing the duplicated button list in this navbar. The navbar consists of two toolbars, one show on desktop, one on mobile. I don't want to include the buttons in each toolbar, I'd prefer to use a common template / directive / component. But the buttons needs a different material directive in each toolbar.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="full-size">
    <span>
        <a [routerLink]="['/']">Brand</a>
    </span>
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/demo']">Demo</button>
    <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>
    <button mat-button color="accent" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Sign Up</button>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="compressed">
    <span>
        <a [routerLink]="['/']">Brand</a>
    </span>

    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>

    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <div app-nav-menu [isCollapsed]="true"></div>
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/demo']">Demo</button>
        <button mat-menu-item [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>
        <button mat-menu-item color="accent" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Sign Up</button>
    </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Which I hope to fix with something like:
    ...
    
    ....
    
    ....

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you can opt for conditional buttons instead of conditional directives. see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5019

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
<button *ngIf="isCollapsed;else matButton" ng dynamic-attr="mat-menu-item" 
[routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>

<ng-template #matButton>
  <button *ngIf= "isCollapsed == false" ng dynamic-attr="mat-button" 
  [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have stated in question that I want to avoid if /else. I want to avoid writing out the buttons twice.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is to change the style, you can add an ngClass and override the current class that the directive adds. For example:

```
      <button mat-stroked-button [ngClass]="{'mat-raised-button': view === 'show'}"
    color="primary" (click)="switchView('show')">Show</button>
      <button mat-stroked-button [ngClass]="{'mat-raised-button': view === 'edit'}"
    color="primary" (click)="switchView('edit')">Edit</button>
```

In this sample you set the buttons to mat-stroked-button, but depending on the view it changes the style to mat-raised-button.

Answer (score -1):

```
<button *ngIf="isCollapsed == true" ng dynamic-attr="mat-menu-item" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>

<button *ngIf= "isCollapsed == false" ng dynamic-attr="mat-button" [routerLink]="['/about']">About</button>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I should have stated in question that I want to avoid if /else. I want to avoid writing out the buttons twice.